# What does a stacktrace mean when there are two of them?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC application and it has essentially two stacktraces, im wondering why there are two of them though?..

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +67

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'PteDotNet.Web.Controllers.BlogController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +232
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +13
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +124
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970356
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is a stacktrace of an inner exception.

It looks like you first got a `MissingMethodException`, with reason

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

That caused an `InvalidOperationException`, with reason

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'PteDotNet.Web.Controllers.BlogController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

So apparently your `BlogController` needs a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not completely sure, but It looks like the Root Cause:

The `MissingMethodException` is fired first, then the `InvalidOperationException` gets fired, because of the first Exceptin

Answer (score 0):

The `InvalidOperationException` is the exception thrown, but it is thrown as a result of a `MissingMethodException` and this exception is included as the `InnerException` of the `InvalidOperationException`. The `InvalidOperationException` explains what went wrong but looking at the `InnerException` you can see where the failure was triggered in the first place.

When you evaluate `ToString()` on an exception with an inner exception you get stack traces of all nested inner exceptions to help you understand the problem. A common mistake is to use `ex.Message + ex.StackTrace` for diagnostics purposes but you loose information about inner exceptions. Unless you want to hide this valuable information you should always use `ex.ToString()` when logging exceptions.

In the MVC framework there is code similar to this:

```
try {
  // Will throw MissingMethodException if there is no parameterless constructor.
  var controller =  Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  ...
}
catch (MissingMethodException ex) {
  var message = String.Format("An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type '{0}'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.", type);
  throw new InvalidOperationException(message, ex);
}
```

So instead of getting a `MissingMethodException` which might confuse you, you get an `InvalidOperationException` with a nice explanation. This is an example of best practice when it comes to exception handling.